# Python/Kivy : focus not set when use mouse

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy`.
If i click on `ok` button using `mouse` then function calls `on_press : root.abc()`.

```
def abc(self):
    if self.test1.text.strip() == "":
        self.test1.focus = True
        return False
```

In this function I check if `test1` textInput is blank then cursor focused into blank `TextInput`.

```
self.test1.focus = True
```

But it is not focused into `TextInput` when i call this function using mouse.Someone help me that how to set focus into `TextInput` when i click on `ok` button using `mouse`?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (300, 100)


class User(Screen):
    test3 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if self.test3.focus and keycode == 40:  # 40 - Enter key pressed
            self.test3.focus = False
            self.abc()
            return True

    def abc(self):
        if self.test1.text.strip() == "":
            self.test1.focus = True
            return False


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

User:
    test1 : test1
    test3: test3
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id:test1
            focus : True
            text: ' '
            width: 100
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

        TextInput:
            id:test2
            text: ' '
            width: 100
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate:
                test3.background_normal = ''
                test3.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]    # 50% translucent blue
                test3.focus = True

        Button:
            id:test3
            text: 'Ok'
            focus: False
            on_press : root.abc()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `on_release` since `on_press` is called as soon as the button is pressed, an instant later the mouse reclaims the focus since it is pressing the button, on the other hand when it is finished pressing no one will claim the focus.

```
Button:
    id:test3
    text: 'Ok'
    focus: False
    on_release : root.abc()
```